# Laravel hasActiveOneOfMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Obviously this does not exist but I am looking for a way to implement it.

Example, I am playing a game where I have 3 teams but I can only be actively playing for one team at any time and when I switch team I essentially starting from the beginning but I would like to retain the progress if I switch team.

My tables would look something like this:

Users:

- active_team_id

TeamProgress:

- user_id
- team_id
- team_level
- team_xp

TeamNames:

- id
- team_name

So there would only be 3 teams defined in TeamNames and while any one of these 3 are active (as set in active_team_id in the users table) then I want to be able to directly target it with something like

```
$user->teamProgress->update()
```

and update the active team directly.

Similarly I would like to do something like

```
$user->teamProgress->get()
```

and just get the team progress for that users active team while a few others may exist within team progress.

Then if I switch the `active_team_id` on the user table and do the same calls above I now update / get info for the second team specified in `active_team_id`

Is there a way to do this with a relation or am I overthinking this and better off doing this by just directly targeting the `TeamProgress` model using the information I already have as a user?

```
$teamProgress->where('user_id', $user->id)->where('team_id', $user->active_team_id)->get()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships. It allows you to define relations by matching multiple columns. For example

```
class User extends Model
{
    use \Awobaz\Compoships\Compoships;
    
    public function activeTeamProgress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TeamProgress::class, ['id', 'active_team_id'], ['user_id', 'team_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I am looking for! Although I was hoping to keep it within Laravel haha...thanks!

Comment: @MatthewJonat it's up to you. I think you can just add methods for getting and updating active progress to the User model.